# Sort 3d array into 2 seperate arrays php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array just like the one below but with more people.

I want to get a separate array(s) for values such as age which would be [22, 13, 19], like a function I can call like this;-

```
sort($ageArray, "age");

function sort (newArray, value)
{
    foreach (index in mainArray)
    {
        array_push(newArray, mainArray("age")
    }
}
```

I know thats wrong but something like that would be nice

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
    [username] => Admin 
    [age] => 22 
    [gender] => M 
    [email] => Admin@gmail.com 
    [kills] => 10 [deaths] => 3 
    [score] => 33000 
    [posts] => 5 ) 
[1] => Array ( 
    [username] => Jack23 
    [age] => 13 
    [gender] => M 
    [email] => Jack23@gmail.com 
    [kills] => 23 
    [deaths] => 22 
    [score] => 52000 
    [posts] => 0 ) 
[2] => Array ( 
    [username] => LucySmith 
    [age] => 19 
    [gender] => F 
    [email] => Lucy2@hotmail.com 
    [kills] => 5 
    [deaths] => 52 
    [score] => 2400 
    [posts] => 0 ))
```

I managed to come up with this

```
$a = array_values($mainArray);
$b = array_values($a[0]);
echo $b[0];
```

which echos "admin", so I could in theory put that in a loop to echo all the usernames and put them in the array but how would I do it for stuff like age, or posts?

Comment: [array_column()](http://be2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php): `$ages = array_column($myArray, 'age');`

Comment: sec let me try this

Comment: like this? 
`array_column(): $ages = array_column($dataArray, 'age');
print_r($ages);` ?

Comment: No, without the `array_column():`.... that was link to the docs, not a piece of code

Comment: cool thank works perfect, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get result using  `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($ageArray as $array)
{
$age[] = $array['age'];
}

print_r($age);//prints array of ages
```

Comment: @Rachel Dockter glad to help.

Comment: @RachelDockter  no doubt that this is a solution, but `array_column()` will be more accurate answer . Thanks

Comment: @ Anant your answer is already provided in comment by Mark Baker.how can you measure accuracy of answers?

Comment: @RachelDockter  and  hekmat    check the time difference between these [mine](https://eval.in/737005) and [yours](https://eval.in/737047) .Currently there are only two values in the array. Think what happen when array has more elements. Also array_column have one more benefit which is stated by AbraCadaver  and added in my solution

Answer (score 2):

Based on the manual:-http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

you need to use `array_column()` like below:-

```
$ages = array_column($myArray, 'age');
```

Also you can do it like below(@AbraCadaver  suggested):-

```
$ages = array_column($dataArray, 'age', 'username');
```

So you can do `echo $ages['Admin'];`

Example output:- https://eval.in/737005

Comment: Might also want `$ages = array_column($dataArray, 'age', 'username');`  So you can do `echo $ages['Admin'];`